# Multiple users' damage for file system

Tags: user-management

Recently I am experiencing different small inconvinences, like alias file gone or terminal does not complete commands with arrow-up. Can it be because like 4 or 5 different users work sometimes on my machine?

Comment: How did you create the additional users? in particular how did you specify their login shells and home directories?

Comment: So... how did whoever implemented the policy do it? user accounts don't just happen. You can check their login shells and home dirs with `getent passwd $USER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they all use the same user, yes it could be the case.

It might also be the case if they have write access to your user home that those things can happen since they could delete your files.

If none of these things apply to you then someone having `sudo` rights could still remove your `.bash_history` (your arrow up for commands) and your aliases file.

Comment: Thanks for answer! No, they work on another user, but do have an axcess to my home dir..

Answer (score 0):

The terminal complete the command with the tab key. Normally this aren't problem related to number of user on system, but if the other user have admin privileges they may have changed something.